# How can I make this Worley noise generator more efficient?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class worley : MonoBehaviour{
public Material mate;
int size = 1000;
int subdiv = 4;

float mindist(Vector2[] vecarr, Vector2 pointe){
    float mindis = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < vecarr.Length; i++){
        float dist = Vector2.Distance(vecarr[i], pointe) / size;
        mindis = Mathf.Min(dist, mindis);
    }

    return mindis;
}

Texture2D worley(Texture2D textu, int sizee, int subdivi){
    Vector2[] pointss = new Vector2[subdivi * subdivi];

    for (int i = 0; i < subdivi * subdivi; i++){
        pointss[i] = new Vector2(Random.Range(0, 1000), Random.Range(0, 1000));
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < sizee; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < sizee; y++){
            float md = mindist(pointss, new Vector2(x, y));
            textu.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(md,md,md,1f));
        }
    }
    textu.Apply();
    return textu;
}

void Start(){
    Texture2D tex = worley(new Texture2D(size, size), size, subdiv);
    mate.SetTexture("_MainTex", tex);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean with efficent? Is it taking too long for calculation? Is the generation wrong? You do not want to generate it every time?

Comment: @Zibelas  I'm a new to writing scripts. The code works fine. It takes about 0.75 second to generate this texture, but I wanted to know if the structure of my code is as optimal as it can be. Can it be optimised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In computer science parlance, the work you're doing in this code is called "[embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)". You're doing the same calculation for a million pixels, and each of those million results does not depend on knowing the results from another one.

So the best way to make this efficient is to move it off the CPU entirely. Rather than computing those million results one at a time, throw it at the GPU what can run waves of them in parallel! This not only cuts down on start-to-finish processing latency, but it keeps all the texture memory writing GPU-side, so you're not bottlenecked by shunting that data across the memory bus.

We can make this type of noise efficient enough that it can be sampled on-demand in a shader in many applications, rather than writing it out to a texture to be read back in (which costs memory and texture sampling bandwidth and loses precision to quantization).

Here's a quick Unity shader implementation, based on some of [Inigo Quilez's published examples](https://iquilezles.org/articles/). (His articles also show how to achieve some extra bells and whistles like [smooth blending between Voronoi cells](https://iquilezles.org/articles/smoothvoronoi/) or [distance functions from the closest edge](https://iquilezles.org/articles/voronoilines/))

```
Shader "Unlit/Worley" {
    Properties {
        _Density ("Density", float) = 8
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            float _Density;

            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv * _Density;
                return o;
            }

            // 2-component hash function borrowed from Inigo Quilez's
            // "Voronoi - smooth" ShaderToy demo:
            // https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldB3zc
            float2 hash2(float2  p ) { 
                p = float2( dot(p, float2(127.1f, 311.7f)), 
                            dot(p, float2(269.5f, 183.3f))); 
                return frac(sin(p)*43758.5453f); 
            }

            float worley(float2 p) {
                // Which integer grid cell are we in?
                float2 cell = floor(p);
                // Where are we within that cell [0-1)?
                float2 inCell = p - cell;

                // Farthest a point can be from closest seed point
                // is one square diagonal, which is sqrt(2) away.
                float smallestSquared = 2.0f;
                // Iterate over the 3x3 block of nearby grid cells. 
                for(int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
                    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
                        // Compute the position of the seed point in that cell
                        // relative to this cell.
                        float2 shift = float2(x, y);
                        float2 seed = hash2(cell + shift) + shift;

                        // Compute distance from sample point to the seed point.
                        float2 sampleToSeed = seed - inCell;
                        float squaredDistance = dot(sampleToSeed, sampleToSeed);

                        // Keep the smallest squared distance.
                        smallestSquared = min(smallestSquared,
                                              squaredDistance);
                    }
                }               
                
                // Normalize so farthest possible distance is 1,
                // and square root to get linear length.
                return sqrt(smallestSquared/2.0f);
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return float4(worley(i.uv).xxx, 1.0f);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea here is to divide our domain into some number of grid cells - controlled by the `_Density` parameter in this shader. In each grid cell, we'll pseudo-randomly scatter a seed point, using the `hash2` function so that we always get the *same* pseudo-random point for a given grid cell. To sample the Worley noise, we just need to check the seed point in the grid cell containing our sample point, and the 8 neighbouring grid cells (since a sample on the edge of a grid cell might be farther from the seed point in its own cell than it is from the point in the neighbouring cell).

[image: Example of resulting noise at two densities]

This gives you a wonderful scaling property: it costs the same amount of work to render `width` x `height` pixels of Worley noise containing 1 seed point as it does to render that same `width` x `height` pixels' worth with a million seed points! No matter how many seeds you have in total, each pixel only needs to peek at 9 of them. Try cranking up the `_Density` to a ridiculous value and notice the material still renders in real time.

Because of this, as I alluded earlier, you might not need to write this noise to a texture at all. You may find it's cheap enough to just call the `worley()` function with your sample coordinates instead. But if you do want to write this to a texture, you can create a `RenderTexture` and stamp a material using this shader into it with `Graphics.Blit()`.

---

If you want to keep this work CPU-side, there are some simple best-practice improvements you can make for a modest speed-up, without radically altering your approach.

- Don't set pixels one at a time. Make a CPU-side array to store all your new colour values, then set them all at once.
- When trying to find the smallest distance in a collection, you can defer the square root part of the computation until the end. (if \$0 \le x < y\$, then \$x^2 < y^2\$ so you still get the correct minimum while saving an expensive transcendental computation)
- When dividing millions of points by the same constant, it's faster to calculate the reciprocal once and multiply by it.

With those adjustments, your inner loop looks more like this:

```
static float MinDistance(Vector2[] seeds, Vector2 sample) {
    // Start the loop with the first distance, so we call Min() one time fewer.
    float minSquared = (seeds[0] - sample).sqrMagnitude;
    for (int i = 1; i < seeds.Length; i++) {
        minSquared = Mathf.Min(minSquared, (seeds[i] - sample).sqrMagnitude);
    }
    // Perform the expensive square root only once, on the distance we want to keep.
    return Mathf.Sqrt(minSquared);
}

// ...then later, in your texture-filling routine...

   // Make our CPU-side staging buffer (borrow some temp memory we can release later).
   var staging = System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Rent(size * size);

   // Constant conversion factor from pixel distance to 0-255 brightness.
   float distanceScale = 255f/size;

   int texelIndex = 0;
   for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
            float md = MinDistance(points, new Vector2(x, y));

            // Perform conversion once, rather than once per channel.
            byte value = (byte)Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Min(md * distanceScale, 255));
            // Using Color32 is cheaper than Color when we don't need float precision.
            staging[texelIndex++] = new Color32(value, value, value, 255);
        }
    }

    // Write the textures all at once.
    texture.SetPixels32(staging);

    // Recycle the temporary array we rented.
    System.Buffers.ArrayPool<Color32>.Shared.Return(staging);

    texture.Apply();
```

The next stage beyond this would be to not check every seed point for every pixel. A pixel in the bottom-left of the texture probably doesn't need to check a seed point in the top-right - something else will almost certainly be closer. You can arrange your points into a [spatial partition](http://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html) so each pixel only has to visit a few of them. We used a version of that trick in the shader approach, ensuring each pixel only had to look at the seeds in the 9 closest grid cells.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should I learn compute shaders to practice parallel computing? I understand the concept, but I don't know anything about how assigning threads works. And, as I understand, CPU threads and GPU threads work differently, right?

Comment: You don't need a compute shader for this, since a regular fragment shader does the work just fine and handles distributing the work between shader cores for you automatically.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I'll try doing it in an unlit shader. Is there any benefit to using compute shaders? Sebastian Lague talks about them quite often when it comes to parallel computing.

Comment: They're great when you want to do something that isn't drawing an image. Drawing an image has a lot of spatial locality: if you reading/writing from/to one pixel, you're probably doing it with nearby pixels too. The default vertex/fragment paths in GPUs are optimized to take advantage of this and keep those ops from interfering with each other so many can be in flight at once. To a first approximation, compute shaders are good when those optimizations are more of an impediment, because you want to do things like random reads/writes or work that's not very coherent across a group of work units.

Comment: Updated with some example shader code.